# How Spring Integration interacts with Web Service (Jersey)?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, spring-integration

I want to know

> How Spring Integration interacts with Web Service (Jersey):

I want to create a small project from scratch

> Maven, Spring Integration, Java EE, Jersey, MySQL.

I think that:

The **first step** will be:

Adding Spring Integration to the Project.

Create input-channels and output-channel, create beans.

The output-channel will forward the request  `http://localhost:8080/{Project}/{package}/team/Manchester`

to the Web Service (Jersey).

I think it can be something like:

```
@Path(“/team”)
public class TeamService{

    @GET
    @Path(“/{param}”)
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam(“param”) String msg){

        return Response.status(200).entity(msg).build();
    }
}
```

The POJO class `Team`:

```
public class Team(){

  private long id;
  private String name;

  // getters and setters

}
```

In the DB I will have 1 table `team`

```
  __id_|___name____
    1  | Manchester
    2  | Barcelona
```

The second step will be:
Create methods `getTeam()` and `getTeamName()` for receive it's values from DB.

The Spring `xml` should be like?

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway
     id="Team"
     request-channel="inputChannel"
     uri="http://localhost:8080/{Project}/{package}/team/"/>
```

I have read the tutorial of Spring Integration, but I do not quite understand how it interacts with Web Services.

How to pass the data to the Spring Integration?
How the Spring Integration passes the data to the Jersey?

Where can I find an example of a project with a similar tasks?
Or someone knows how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what your inputChannel is.. the mySql DB ? in that case you would need a JDBC inbound adapter that would query it ; the result of the query will be put in a Spring Message. That message will flow through your config until it reaches the outbound-gateway. Here againm depending on your config, messge will be read and a SOAP requets will be performed accordingly for this message.